# App Extension's bundle ID Transfer one account to another account

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode

I have transferred my app to new account, it's move successfully and their bundle id is also visible in new account but my main problem is i am using today extension(widget) with this app,  today extension's bundle id is not transferred in new account, I could not create new bundle id for extension because its update issue for old user

Ex. 
Main app id is  - com.xyz.app (transferred in new account )
**Extension app id - com.xyz.app.myextension (show in old account, not transfer in new account)**

Any one help me.

Comment: Same issue. Might be a glitch. My old account isn't even enrolled anymore.

Answer (score 5):

Go to your old account and then delete your old app id will solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this too and suspect it's a glitch. I don't think my old account even has the app ID, though I didn't try recently. I ended up simply choosing a different bundle ID for the share extension only. Haven't encountered any consequences.